# My lawn mower still started and ran with spark plug detached

Tags: lawnmower

How is it possible? I realized after finishing lawn mow, that the spark plug was detached.  I 100% sure it was detached the whole time because I went to get gas and the kids were around, and I didn’t want them playing with it.  When I came back I didn’t attach it.  It started up and ran fine though.  I only realized after finishing the mow it was still out.

Comment: A spark can jump a few mm from spark pug wire to the terminal. Alternatively, you're using diesel fuel in a high-compression engine.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by “detached”?

Comment: "How is it possible? " Its not, you were in the Twilight Zone ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Spark can jump to the plug if it's close enough, or short through the block enough to fire -  especially on small engines.